# Double Variable Expansion From For Loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to find out how I can define variables within a for loop.   They 
 must equal the values of pre-defined variables with the for loop variable being a part of those pre-defined variables names.

Example:

```
PROCESS1="sshd"    --> 1 will be a for loop variable 'i' value
ALIAS1=SSH
PROCESS2="snmpd"   --> 2 will be a for loop variable 'i' value
ALIAS2=SNMP

#Creating array consisting of n number of processes to feed to the for loop

ARRAY=(1 2)

for i in ${ARRAY[@]]};do
PID$i=`ps -elf | grep -i $PROCESS$i`  -->   this is where I am getting stuck
TCP$i=`netstat -anlp | grep $PID$i
done
```

I am trying to create PID1 equal to the value of the "ps" command output with grepping for the value of variable PROCESS1.

I've even tried this:

```
for i in ${ARRAY[@]]};do

PROCESS=PROCESS$i
ALIAS=ALIASP$i
PID=PID$i

PID$i=`ps -elf | grep -i $$PROCESS`
TCP$i=`netstat -anlp | grep $$PID
```

This only attempts to grep for "PROCESS1" instead of sshd.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use bash arrays?:

```
PROCESS=(sshd snmpd)
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#PROCESS[@]}-1)));do
    PID[$i]=$(pgrep "${PROCESS[$i]}")
    TCP[$i]=$(netstat -anlp | grep ${PID[$i]})
done
echo ${#PID[0]} ${#TCP[0]} ${#PID[1]} ${#TCP[1]}
```

Use bash associative arrays for fun:

```
PROCESS=(sshd snmpd)
declare -A PID TCP
for i in ${PROCESS[@]};do
    PID[$i]=$(pgrep "$i")
    TCP[$i]=$(netstat -anlp | grep ${PID[$i]})
done
echo ${#PID[sshd]} ${#TCP[sshd]} ${#PID[snmpd]} ${#TCP[snmpd]}
```

Use declare, get variable value using indirect reference, if you must:

```
PROCESS=(sshd snmpd)
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#PROCESS[@]}-1)));do
    declare PID$i="$(pgrep "${PROCESS[$i]}")"
    ref=PID$i
    declare TCP$i="$(netstat -anlp | grep ${!ref})"
done
echo ${#PID0} ${#TCP0} ${#PID1} ${#TCP1}
```

Never use eval:

```
PROCESS=(sshd snmpd)
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#PROCESS[@]}-1)));do
    eval "PID$i=\"$(pgrep "${PROCESS[$i]}")\""
    eval "TCP$i=\"\$(netstat -anlp | grep \$PID$i)\""
done
echo ${#PID0} ${#TCP0} ${#PID1} ${#TCP1}
```

Comment: You were asking about defining variables with a loop, i provided an answer. Please, don't fall into [XY proble](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking for [variable parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#variable_name_expansion). To iterate over PID* variables just do `for i in ${!PID@}; do echo $i=${!i}; done`